# Javascript setInterval is not populating value in IE8

Tags: javascript

I have web UI in which I am refreshing values on my web page after 2secs. What I observed is that it works well in chrome but not in IE. I tried to find solution that are provided on other forums but that are not working. I treid to put alert in my javascript, it shows the same values in IE and updated values in chrome.

I would like to know whether there is anything in javascript needs to handle in order to work it in IE 8.0

```
setInterval(xmlfunc(),2000);
var myval=Function(xmlhttp.responseText,"MYVAL");
```

Regds

Comment: Are you sure you intend to call `xmlfunc` only once, and assign its return value to be executed repeatedly?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `setInterval(xmlfunc,2000);` without invoking the function? I think you might want to read [How to return the value from an AJAX call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593)

Comment: xmlfunc gets call everytime. As I mentioned it is working on Chrome and not in IE. it gets invoked everytime.

Comment: when I tried to debug using alert, I found that xmlhttp.responseText (XMLHttpRequest) is same for IE and it gets updating in case of Chrome.

Comment: can you post the ajax part of your xmlhttp function?